# How to compare numerical values between two lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return the first value of a list which is larger than the element of another list. 
Take for example on the lists A and B below,

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
B = [5, 7, 9, 11]
```

for `B[0] = 5`, I want it to return the first element of list A which is bigger than 5. In this case, the returned value is `A[2] = 6`. Then repeat this to all elements of B.

The expected end result would be a list `C = [6, 8, 10, 12]`

I thought of 2 iterators, i and j but for some reason which I can't understand, j in the code below is not iterating.

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
B = [5, 7, 9, 11]

j=0
for i in range(len(B)):
    while B[i] < A[j]:
        j+=1
    else:
        print(A[j])
```

The result I am getting is:

```
2
2
2
2
```

Does anyone see where the error is?

Comment: Because all the values of your list `B` are greater than the first value of your list `A` (2) so `B[i] < A[j]` is never true.

Comment: C = [j for i in B for j in A if j > i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two loops, for each element `i` of `B` find the first element `j` of `A` which is bigger that `i` and if found then break the loop and move to the next element in `B`. Try this :

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
B = [5, 7, 9, 11]
C = []
for i in B:
    for j in A:
        if j>i:
            C.append(j)
            break
```

**Output** :

```
[6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
B = [5, 7, 9, 11]
for y in B:
    for x in A:
        if x>y:
            print(x)
            break
```

---

Output

```
6
8
10
12
```

Comment: This is returning all the elements bigger than the one being tested. It is different then what I was looking for as was just the first element of A above each one in B. When I changed A to test consistency the code broke.

Comment: @RafaelCasteloBranco It was a typo

Comment: @RafaelCasteloBranco It's not fair for accepting my answer over Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev's, his answer is earlier than mine.

Comment: Stackoverflow is showing me you answered it 12 minutes before him, that is why I accepted your answer. But I already changed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @RafaelCasteloBranco btw, the key point of this problem is to break the loop when the condition is `x>y` is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, I am the past 20min understanding what the code is doing to figure out why I did it wrong. Thanks for the comments and explanation

Answer (score 0):

By using a list comprehension:

```
C = [j for i in B for j in A if j > i]
```

Result:

```
[6, 8, 10, 12, 8, 10, 12, 10, 12, 12]
```

Basically, we need to iterate through each element. My code starts with **B**, then goes for each **A** until finishes. Then the same cycle happens again. For each iteration, the code checks whether A[j] > B[i] or not; if it's greater, keep the value in a list **C**.

For one iteration

```
C = [i for i in A if i > B[0]]
# [6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: As a final step to get OP's output, you can remove the duplicates using `list(dict.fromkeys(C))`

Comment: @Silveris I thought he wanted all element from B, according to 'Then repeat this to all elements of B'.

Comment: I changed the A list to check consistency and the results are not what I was expected. With A = [2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], C =  [2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12] instead of C = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops because you want to compare every element of B with every Element of A

```
    for element in B:
        for number in A:
            if number > element:
                print(number)
```

Output: `[6, 8, 10, 12, 8, 10, 12, 10, 12, 12]`

Comment: This is returning all the elements bigger than the one being tested. It is different then what I was looking for as was just the first element of A above each one in B. When I changed A to test consistency the code broke